# ¿Cómo importar/instalar un módulo con pyCharm?

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

Acabo de descargarme PyCharm (Community Edition 5.0.3). Tengo un par de proyectos personales con Python que usan [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) como framework para Web.

Si ejecuto mis `*.py` desde consola se levanta el servidor, escucha en el puerto indicado y todo funciona bien. Desde el proyecto de PyCharm, el editor ya me avisa de que no "hay un módulo llamado bottle" y efectivamente al intentar ejecutar:

```
ImportError: No module named bottle

Process finished with exit code 1
```

¿Cómo hago para añadir módulos en PyCharm?

Answer (score 4):

La [respuesta de @jachguate](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/2622/21) es correcta pero, si he entendido bien tu pregunta, creo que tienes un problema de Concepción del entorno en Python.

Python se instala en tu sistema en una ruta determinada, aunque se establecen asociaciones a comandos en tu SO para que puedas ejecutarlo desde cualquier ruta.

Los paquetes que instalan se guardan en la carpeta de paquetes de la versión de Python con que se ejecutó. Si compilas manualmente una biblioteca, si lo ejecutas con Pyhon 2.7 se instalará para esa versión, mientras que si lo haces con Python 3.5, lo hará con este.

Lo mismo ocurre al instalar paquetes con `pip`, que los instala en la ruta de Python a la que está asociada la aplicación. Para evitar problemas de incompatibilidad, tanto pip como Python aceptan dualidad de llamada, es decir, si añades como sufijo la versión del lenguaje que quieres usar, ese intérprete será el que se ejecute y, por consiguiente, los paquetes que instales, lo harán en la carpeta que corresponde a ese intérprete.

Cuando ejecutas una aplicación / fichero `.py` con una versión determinada de Python, al hacer una llamada `import`, el intérprete busca en la carpeta de la versión que llamaste, a no ser que explícitamente lo declares en el código.

Al trabajar con IDE's, lo recomendable (y que todos los IDE's suelen traer por defecto) es instalar un virtualenv / similar en la carpeta de desarrollo, de forma tal que se instale una versión de Python dentro de tu entorno, así que todo lo que instales se guarde ahí, y no tengas problemas de incompatibilidad.

Además de escoger el intérprete en PyCharm, puedes hacer todas estas cosas que, entre otras muchas razones para llevarlo a cabo, te permiten tener instalado en el sistema no sólo varias versiones de Python y ejecutarlas a tu gusto (o necesidad), sino que también puedes hacerlo con paquetes (bibliotecas / librerías), lo cual te ayuda con la migración de tus aplicaciones y la compatibilidad de las mismas al actualizar un paquete para una aplicación pero no para otra.

Espero que mi aporte, lejos de servirte de ayuda inmediata, te ayude a comprender cómo funciona `virtualenv`, una herramienta muy útil que te servirá para desarrollo profesional.

Answer (score 2):

### Añadir la ruta

Ve a Settings -> Project Settings -> Project Interpreter.

Presiona *configure interpreter* y navega a la pestaña *Paths*

[image: pycharm path tab]

Presiona el botón + en el área *Paths*. Puedes poner la ruta al módulo que quires que sea reconocido.

#### Si no sabes la ruta..

Abre el intérprete python, donde puedes importar el módulo.

```
>> import gnuradio
>> gnuradio.__file__
"path/to/gnuradio"
```

Comunmente se tiene una estructura de carpetas como esta:

```
foobarbaz/
  gnuradio/
    __init__.py
    other_file.py
```

Y quieres agregar *foobarbaz* a la ruta .

**PyCharm Professional 3.4**

Si tienes PyCharm Professional 3.4, para añadir la ruta, debes ir a  "Preferences" --> "Project Interpreter" y seleccionar el tool button que se encuentra en la esquina superior derecha.

Allí seleccionas "More..." --> "Show path for the selected interpreter" --> "Add".

Allí puedes entonces agregar la ruta.

Respuesta traducida de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19885882/255257 y https://stackoverflow.com/a/27007843/255257

Comment: Échale un vistazo a mi repuesta, por favor! :-) Ah, y te recomiendo que actualices tu PyCharm, vamos ya por la versión 5.1!

Comment: @JuanRocamonde, gracias. Mi versión es 5.0.3, build del 22 diciembre 2015 (si es que lo descargué e instalé la semana pasada). En mi versión no puedo encontrar "settings" como dice esta respuesta y sólo "default settings -> default project" y ahí al project interpreter le puedo añadir librerías/módulos. Entonces todo funciona. Estoy instalando así en un `env` virtual o local para PyCharm? Sigo sin entender que usando el mismo intérprete que por consola uno funcione y otro no.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, te recomiendo que uses entornos virtuales para no tirarte tu sistema por estar instalando cosas que podrían conflictuar.

Por PyCharm no te preocupes amigo, cuando tu abres tu proyecto de Python este va a detectar el compilador de la máquina virtual como el compilador por defecto, claro está, si la máquina está debidamente registrada en el sistema, o sea, la hiciste en ese sistema.

Luego puedes usar `pip`, `virtualenv` instala la máquina con `pip`, para poder instalar lo que quieras. Desde PyCharm puedes ejecutar terminal para compilar lo que quieras desde la máquina virtual. Puedes ir a configuraciones, o sea, settings, buscar proyecto, o project y verás dos opciones, estructura del directorio del proyecto e intérprete, en intérprete verás el compilador python por defecto y una lista de paquetes que tienes instalados, desde ahí mismo verás si están para actualizar y podrás actualizarlos, o instalar nuevo.

Si necesitas consultar algo más escríbeme. Con gusto te puedo ayudar.